# Current line-/col-number in phpQuery?

Tags: php, frameworks, phpquery

How can I get the line-/col-number of the current element in phpQuery?

I use the phpQuery framework for a validation tool with custom errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
__LINE__
```

The above code will get the current line number of a php script. As far as I know, there is no way to get the character number.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)